# How do i add a filter system in wordpress by giving my <div's> data attributes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am at the moment trying to implement a data-filter system. I want to do this with data-attributtes, where i can filter the posts by categories. i have never done this before, so i dont really know where to start.

I do have my own template where i spit posts out with PHP.
Let say i have 30 posts with 6 categories. 
Let say "horse" has the category animal and so on.
So when i click on the category animal, i would only see the horse, monkey etc.

Here is my code: 
I do have some html added, but i didnt add it because i it is not necessary for this particular post.

```
$vorespartnere = get_posts( array(
'showposts'        => -1,
'post_type'        => 'partnere',
'orderby'          => 'order',
'suppress_filters' => false,
) );

    $terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'partnere-kategorier',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) ); 


if ( ! empty( $vorespartnere ) ) {
  foreach ( $vorespartnere as $partnere ) {
    $image      = get_field( 'partner_logo', $partnere );
    $text       = get_field( 'partner_beskrivelse', $partnere  );
    $overskrift = get_field( 'partner_overskrift', $partnere  );

        if ( ! empty( $image ) && ! is_wp_error() ) {
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="">
        <?php
    }

    if ( ! empty( $text ) && ! is_wp_error() ) {

        echo $text;

    }

    if ( ! empty( $overskrift ) && ! is_wp_error() ) {

        echo $overskrift;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't see any code about <div>, could you add it ?

Comment: Let me put it up in a grid, then i will repost it :) !